# Steps needed to arrive at the Lagrange dual function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

This question is related to the text on page 222-223 on the book Convex Optimization (By Boyd and Vandenberghe). The optimization problem is as follows $$\min. \log(\det(X^{-1}))$$ $$s.t. a_i^TXa_i\leq 1, ~for~ i\in\{1,2\cdots m\}.$$ How to show that the Lagrange dual of above problem is $$\log( \det(\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_ia_ia_i^T))-1^T\lambda +n, ~ for \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_ia_ia_i^T ~ being~ positive ~ definite.$$ I just do not how they obtained the term $\log( \det(\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_ia_ia_i^T))$ in the dual function. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One issue is going from:

$a_{i}^{T}Xa_{i} \leq 1$

to:

$\mbox{tr}((a_{i}a_{i}^{T})X) \leq 1$.

This is done using a couple of standard tricks:

A. Since $\mbox{tr}(s)=s$ for any scalar,

$a_{i}^{T}Xa_{i} = \mbox{tr}(a_{i}^{T}Xa_{i}) \leq 1$.

B. By the cyclic property of the trace of a product,

$\mbox{tr}((a_{i}a_{i}^{T})X) \leq 1$.

2. A second issue is where $f_{0}^{*}(Y)$ comes from.  This is discussed in example 3.23 on page 92 of the book.
3. The final step is applying (5.11) to the problem to get (5.15)

Our primal problem is problem is

$\min \log \det \left( X^{-1} \right) $

subject to

$ \mathcal{A} X \preceq 1 $

where $\mathcal{A}$ is the linear operator

$\mathcal{A}X=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
\mbox{tr}((a_{1}a_{1}^{T})X) \\
\mbox{tr}((a_{2}a_{2}^{T})X) \\
\vdots \\
\mbox{tr}((a_{m}a_{m}^{T})X)
\end{array}
\right]. $

The transpose of $\mathcal{A}$ is

$\mathcal{A}^{T}y=\sum_{i=1}^{m} y_{i} \left( a_{i}a_{i}^{T} \right). $

We have from (5.11) that

$g(\lambda) = \inf_{x} -b^{T}\lambda - f_{0}^{*}(-\mathcal{A}^{T}\lambda)$

where I've suppressed the $\nu$ terms since there are no equality constraints.

Thus

$g(\lambda)=\inf_{x} -1^{T} \lambda -f_{0}^{*}(-\mathcal{A}^{T}\lambda)$

Then

$g(\lambda)=-1^{T}\lambda -\left( \log \det \left( -(-\mathcal{A}^{T}\lambda)^{-1} \right) -n \right)$

as long as $\mathcal{A}^{T}\lambda \succ 0$.

Since $\log \det Z^{-1} = -\log \det Z$ for postivde definite $Z$, this simplifies to

$g(\lambda)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-1^{T}\lambda + \log \det \left( \mathcal{A}^{T}\lambda \right) +n  & \mathcal{A}^{T}\lambda \succ 0 \\
-\infty      & \mbox{otherwise.} 
\end{array}
\right. $

Comment: I know how (5.11) is obtained but I have no clue how to get (5.15) from (5.11). Please help with this step. I know the trace step.

Comment: See expanded answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I do not understand what is the value of special operator $A$ in matrix form?

Comment: The linear operator needs to act on a matrix to produce a vector of values for the left hand side of the inequality $\mathcal{A}X \leq 1$.  This can't be done by matrix multiplication.  If you convert $X$ to a vector by stacking the columns, then you can write this as $A \mbox{vec}(X) \leq 1$ where the rows of the matrix $A$ are the vectorized versions of the matrices $a_{i}a_{i}^{T}$.